# Cranberries on Passover

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, passover, hechsher-certification, chametz-leaven

Are fresh cranberries, bagged with OU (year-round) certification, kosher for Passover?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [cRc](http://www.crcweb.org/fruit%20&%20veg%20guide.php) site:
"Cranberries - Fresh do not require kosher certification. Dried require a reliable kosher certification. "

The Star-K [says](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-problem.htm) that fresh produce bought in a supermarket poses no problem.

Chabad.org [writes](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/493085/jewish/Which-vegetables-may-be-eaten-on-Passover.htm), "Fresh, unprocessed fruits and vegetables, however, do not require certification. "

Page 92 of the OU Passover guide (from 2013) says that frozen fruit needs no certification ("However, these issues are not a concern at facilities that process frozen fruit, which does not require Passover certification.
"), so I would guess that they would agree that, all the more so, fresh fruit doesn't.

Comment: The cRc (sic, not CRC) page you link to is not discussing Passover afaict.

Comment: @msh210 thanks for the clarification. I read through their pesach list and they don't mention any concern with fresh cranberries (unlike raspberries, blueberries and blackberries).

Comment: @msh210 regardless, why would a fresh vegetable require any certification? (***note***: this is not the same thing as *checking* produce, which is still necessary.) Bagged, certified lettuce exists basically to save people the trouble of checking.

Comment: Typically frozen veggies are processed on the same lines that make pasta, this would be an issue obviously. This isn't 100% so you'd want to check accordingly.

Comment: @IsaacKotlocky But the citation in this post is incorrect. The answerer implies the cRc is referring to _Pesach_. You wanna argue fresh berries don't need KFP certification, I won't be on the other side of that argument -- but don't cite that cRc page as support.